# How to read 8-byte integers in GMS 2.x?

Tags: dm-script

I need to read 8-byte integers from a stream. I could not find any documentation how to read 8-byte integers in DM. It would be something similar to a long long integer. 
Is there a trick how to stream 8-byte integers from file in GMS 2.x ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the "Stream" object to read/import data of various kinds. Please refer to the DM Help > Scripting > File Input and Output:

[image: DM Help]

Other examples can also be found at [DM-Script-Database](http://portal.tugraz.at/portal/page/portal/felmi/DM-Script/DM-Script-Database) :

- Read-Ser (http://donation.tugraz.at/dm/source_codes/127)
- JEMS_.ems file reader (http://donation.tugraz.at/dm/source_codes/108)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following (stupid) method to do so:

```
number  readint32(object s){
    number stream_byte_order=2
    number result=0
    TagGroup tg = NewTagGroup(); 
    tg.TagGroupSetTagAsLong( "SInt32_0", 0 )  
    TagGroupReadTagDataFromStream( tg, "SInt32_0", s, stream_byte_order );  
    tg.TagGroupGetTagAsLong( "SInt32_0", result)  
    return result
}

number  readint64(object s){
    //new for reading 8-byte integer in TIA ver >3.7
    //DM automatic convert result to float when the second 4-byte >1
    number result = readint32(s)+ (readint32(s)*4294967296)
    // 4294967296 equals to 0xFFFFFFFF in hex form
    return result
}
```

It works with reading ser <2GB, but does not for larger file. I still did not figure it out...

@09-04-2016

Now i got a solution to the data offset problem in ser:
Here is the solution:

```
Void  b_readint64(object s, number &lo, number &hi){
    //new for reading 8-byte (64bit) integer in TIA ver >3.7
    //read the low and high section individually and later work 
    //together with StreamSetPos32singed, StreamSetPos64 funcsions
    lo = b_readint32(s)
    hi = b_readint32(s)
}

Void StreamSetPos32Signed(object s, number base, number lo){
if (lo>0) StreamSetPos(s, base, lo)
else      StreamSetPos(s, base, 4294967296+lo)
}

Void StreamSetPos64(object s, number base, number lo, number hi){
    if (hi!=0){
        StreamSetPos(s, base, 0)
        for (number i=0; i<hi; i++) StreamSetPos(s, 1, 4294967296)
        StreamSetPos32Signed(s, 1, lo)
    } else  StreamSetPos32signed(s, base, lo)
}
```

BTW, I just uploaded this upgraded script to 
http://portal.tugraz.at/portal/page/portal/felmi/DM-Script/DM-Script-Database

Comment: Note: The "number" variable in GMS is not suitable to store 64bit integer values, so your "result" variable in the 2nd method will be problematic, I guess. .

Comment: @BmyGuest store the 64bit integer to two 32bit integer may be a solution to store the value. And it now works to read .ser file larger than 2GB (up to 8192EB).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like an 8-byte integer in DigitalMicrograph. You can use the streaming to read in two successive 4-byte sections as integers (See answer above) and then display them as binary using `binary()` or hexadecimal using `hex()`, but you will have to do the maths yourself for the "meaning" of the 8-byte integer (storing it as real-number).  You can use the binary operators & | ^ for bitwise numeric, when needed.